# Get the key of an object in custom watchers (Vue Js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

It's possible to get the key in the watcher from a specific value?

For example if I have this object

```
data() {
   return {
     form: {
        a: 'A',
        b: 'B'
     }
   }
}
```

If the value from **a** is updated i want to get his key.

```
 watch: {
      'form' (val) : {
         //get the key 
       }
   }
```

I know i can watch the specific value this way: `'form.a'(val) {}` but for some purpose i need to get the keys from the object.

Thanks

Ps: Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
watch: {
    form: {
        handler(newVal, oldVal) {
            let relevant = newVal.a
            //whatever you needed to do to that
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

or you could use `Object.keys(val)` to get the `form` data object property keys as follow :

```
    watch: {
     'form' (val) : {
        let keys= Object.keys(val)// gives ["a", "b"]
      // and do whatever you want with that keys
      }
   }
```

Comment: I'm trying the second example but not getting value in console `'form' (val) {
                let value = Object.keys(val);
                console.log(value);
            }` and already tried the first example but is returning the whole object